UseFocusEffect calls backend multiple times in a second
I have this component which has two tabs, my groups and all groups.
The user can join the group and leave the group. When the user leaves the group, the app navigates to this screen, a new request should be sent to the server to fetch the new groupsOwn and render the new my groups. At the moment, it sends too many requests to the server, any suggestions on how I should fix this?
const GroupsSection: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { isAll } = route?.params;
  const { apiCall } = useTheme() as unknown as AppTheme;
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = React.useState('');
  const [pageOwn, setPageOwn] = React.useState(1);
  const [pageAll, setPageAll] = React.useState(1);

  const debounced = debounce(search);

  const {
    data: groupsOwn,
    loading: loadingOwn,
    error: errorOwn,
    refreshError: refreshErrorOwn,
    setData: setDataOwn,
    refetch: refetechOwn,
    setRefreshing: setRefreshingOwn,
  } = useFetchData<Community[]>(
    '/services/community_page_overview?allGroups=0&page=0&search=&sort_by=name&sort_dir=ASC'
  );

  const {
    data: groupsAll,
    loading: loadingAll,
    error: errorAll,
    refreshError: refreshErrorAll,
    setData: setDataAll,
    refetch: refetechAll,
    setRefreshing: setRefreshingAll,
  } = useFetchData<Community[]>(
    '/services/community_page_overview?allGroups=1&page=0&search=&sort_by=name&sort_dir=ASC'
  );

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
    
      if (!refetechOwn && !isAll ) {
        setRefreshingOwn(true);
      }
      else if(refetechOwn && !isAll){
        if (groupsOwn && groupsOwn?.length > 0) {
          setDataOwn([...groupsOwn]);}
        else {
          setDataOwn([])};
      }
      if(!refetechAll && isAll)
      {
        setRefreshingAll(true);
      }else if(refetechAll && isAll){

        if (groupsAll?.length > 0) {
          setDataAll([...groupsAll]);
        }
        else setDataAll([]);
      }

      
    }, [groupsOwn])
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.groupsView}>
      {!isAll ? (
        <FlatList
          style={styles.groupsSection}
          data={groupsOwn}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <GroupsCard
              community={item}
              key={item.gid}
            />
          )}
          onEndReached={groupsOwn?.length > 5 ? fetchMoreOwn : null}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.3}
          ListEmptyComponent={() => (
            <NoContent
              title="No Groups Found"
              subTitle=" "
            />
          )}
        />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.groupsSection}>
          <View style={styles.searchView}>
            <AppInput
              label={`Search Groups (${
                groupsAll?.length || '-'
              } groups)`}
              style={styles.searchInput}
              value={searchString}
              onChangeText={async (value) => await setSearchString(value)}
            />
          </View>
          <FlatList
            data={groupsAll}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              <GroupsCard
                community={item}
                key={item.gid}
              />
            )}
            onEndReached={groupsAll?.length > 5 ? fetchMoreAll : null}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.3}
            ListEmptyComponent={() => (
              <NoContent
                title="No Groups Found"
                subTitle=" "
              />
            )}
          />
        </View>
      )}
      {refreshErrorOwn && (
        <Toast message={refreshErrorOwn.message} type="error" />
      )}

      {refreshErrorAll && (
        <Toast message={refreshErrorAll.message} type="error" />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default GroupsSection;

I tried removing the groupsOwn callback trigger in useFocusEffect, it works but when there is only one group and after the user leaves the group, the single group is still rendered and stays there. In other words, it does not enter the else blcok of first else if statement:
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
    
      if (!refetechOwn && !isAll ) {
        setRefreshingOwn(true);
      }
      else if(refetechOwn && !isAll){
        if (groupsOwn && groupsOwn?.length > 0) {
          setDataOwn([...groupsOwn]);}
        else {
        console.log("It does not enter here, the groupsOwn.length is still 1");
          setDataOwn([])};
      }
      if(!refetechAll && isAll)
      {
        setRefreshingAll(true);
      }else if(refetechAll && isAll){

        if (groupsAll?.length > 0) {
          setDataAll([...groupsAll]);
        }
        else setDataAll([]);
      }

      
    }, [])
  );


